# Using if clause instead of processor #ifdef

Tags: c, compiler-flags

I am using a `#ifdef` block to conditionally include a block of code based on -`Dflag` passed to the compiler.

Is there a way to implement this with an `if`?

Something along the lines of:

```
if (defined(flag)) {

}
```

Comment: What does the macro expand to?

Comment: that is what I am trying to figure out :P

Comment: With `-Dflag` it evaluates empty (no token at all), but is defined as a preprocessor macro identifier. With `-Dflag=expression` it evaluates to `expression`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use preprocessor to produce a different flag, which could be tested with a run-time `if` statement, like this:

```
#ifdef flag
#define flag_defined 1
#else
#define flag_defined 0
#endif
```

Now you can do this:

```
if (flag_defined) ...
```

Answer (score 5):

If you define a macro so that it evaluates to either zero or nonzero, then you can use it in the condition of the `if` statement. Since it's a compile-time constant, in case it's zero, the dead code eliminator pass in the compiler will remove the unreachable code anyway.

Comment: What would such a macro look like?

Comment: @thenewguy617 `#define MACRO 0` (or 1). Have you read Dasblinkenlight's answer?

Comment: ohh, I thought you were suggesting a augmented macro that took the flag (defined or undefined) and returned 0/1

Comment: @thenewguy617 No, and I don't think you can implement it using the C preprocessor either.

Answer (score 3):

If you are willing to give `flag` a value (0 or 1) instead of defining it or not, you can do

```
cc -Dflag=1 file.c
```

with

```
if (flag) { ... }
```

without messing up your code with ugly `#ifdef`s. You are also protected against forgetting to define `flag` at all: in this case your compiler treats `flag` as an identifier. Since you never declared it, you'll get a compile time error about an undeclared or undefined symbol `flag`.

Comment: I dont want to change the build scripts, but I will keep this mind for next time.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't use a C if statement to check if a preprocessor token is defined.
You can use one of these forms though

```
#ifdef flag
...
#endif

#if defined(flag)
...
#endif
```

You can however check if the token evaluates to a true/false C expression,

if you use `-Dflag=1` you can do

```
if (flag) {
  ...
}
```

And if you want to turn it off, you can define the macro as `-Dflag=0`

Following this you can define a new preprocessor token that you can check with a C if statement. e.g.

```
#ifdef flag
#define FLAG_SET 1
#else
#define FLAG_SET 0
#endif

if(FLAG_SET) { //the flag macro was defined
...
}
```

If all you want to do is is check whether the flag is defined, there's no point to all of this, just use `#ifdef`. With a C `if` statement, the most C compilers will optimize away the code, there's nothing you could change at runtime to get any benefit of not using the preprocessor.

Comment: You can if you think a little outside the box ;)

Comment: @NikBougalis I'm getting to it. But you still cannot test the flag directly, you need to use the preprocessor, e.g. to define a new flag.

Comment: You could... `-DFLAG_VALUE=964`and then `if(FLAG_VALUE == 964) { ... }` will work.

Comment: I want to use `if` and not `#ifdef` so that compiler checks my syntax.

Answer (score 1):

```
#ifdef FLAG
#define FLAG_VALUE 1
#else
#define FLAG_VALUE 0
#endif

int flag = FLAG_VALUE;

...

if(flag)
{
    ....
}
```

Alternatively just use `-DFLAG_VALUE=1` or `-DFLAG_VALUE=0` as appropriate and use `FLAG_VALUE` directly.

If you plan on being able to change the FLAG_VALUE at runtime you will need a variable. If you change in non-obvious ways (e.g. via a debugger or through other loader trickery) make sure to declare it volatile, otherwise the compiler might be able to do dead-code elimination and remove huge chunks of code.

Also, if you don't plan on changing the value of `flag` after initializing, then you should probably make it `const`.

Comment: I thought of this, was curious to see if there was a more elegant solution, thanks.